# Update MongoDB with laravel 5 jenssegers

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5

I tried to make the update document with mongoDB is an update but the problem what I mean is not appropriate. In mongoDB database there are a few users and I want to update user with id: 123 but update not id 123 but first user id 1.

Code:

```
$user = User:: first ([' _ id ', Input:: get [' id ']]);
$user >-email = ' john@foo.com ';
$user >-save ();
```

How to update that document id = 123?

Answer (score 2):

After having many failed attempts, I finally found the right one. And here's the answer:

```
 $user = UpdateUser::where('_id' , '=' , Input::get('id'))->first();
  $user->username = Input::get('usern');
  $user->save()
```

;

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = User::first(Input::get['id']);
$user->email = 'john@foo.com';
$user->save();
```

Comment: Still failed. The update does not match the id in question but the first document.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
$user = User::where('_id',Input::get['id'])
        ->update(['email' => 'john@foo.com']);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Be sure User Model extends `Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model`
2. after first line add this line to see what user fetched!
   `dd($user->toArray());`
3. try this:
   `$user = User::where('_id',Input::get['id']);`

if #3 worked something in your configuration( for using Jenssegers's package ) is wrong!